# how to assign serial port name using rules.d?

Tags: usb, udev, usb-modem, serial-port

The system is Ubuntu 16.04 with two Arduino devices connected via USB cables. When they are connected they appear in `/dev` directory as `ttyACM0` and `ttyACM1`. Is it possible to assign a different name with a slightly different identifier such as `ttyACM5`?

I ran the `udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyACM0 --attribute-walk` command and based on the attributes they are differentiable (have different serial numbers). I tried putting a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` with the lines:

`ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0043", ATTRS{serial}=="55839313738351017091", KERNEL="ttyUSB5", MODE="666"`
and
`ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0043", ATTRS{serial}=="55839313738351017071", KERNEL="ttyUSB5", MODE="666"`

But that didn't fly as the devices came up again as ttyAMC0 and ttyAMC1. Is it possible to assign a serial port a name with a slightly different number? Just a bit of background; I need to make sure the names don't flip flop between ttyACM0 and ttyACM1 after as I have a program establishing communications with these devices using their path (ex: /dev/ttyACM0), and I need the names to be stable after  a PC power cycle, and also when using a USB hub. If assigning a name is off the table, any other options to achieve the desired goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect you shouldn't be trying to assign to the `KERNEL` attribute - try `NAME="ttyUSB5"` or (failing that) `SYMLINK="ttyUSB5"` (which won't change the primary node identifier, but should give you an alternate that you can refer to it by)

Comment: I use something like this: `SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{serial}=="A400g81t", SYMLINK+="scope"
` in that example, the device will be called "scope"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers offered by @steeldriver and @Jean-Marie are both spot on and the `SYMLINK="ttyUSB5"` did work. Essentially it created a link that is a pointer to the name the system creates for the port. Thanks!